# only Finger Print Image using Android Application

Tags: android, image-processing, fingerprint

I want to just capture only finger prints.
Requirement is, those prints should have clear prints , black and white.!
So user should able to read it properly manually.
Does it possible to to capture using mobile camera and them image processing to covert RGB to black & white ?
Please guide me with good example.
Or any other option to archive above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Fingerprint image is capture by a specific sensor as sensor present on IPhone or Galaxy S products.

I don't know solution based on built-in camera.

Comment: @JBCloud, is it useful ?